# Statistical test to test differences between 2 categorical variables

Tags: group-differences, choice-modeling

I have a data set outline preferences for 3 groups of subjects regarding payments and game features. The set looks like this:

|  |  | payment_source_preference |  |  |  |  | favorite_feature |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group | GroupSize | NoPreference | Source1 | Source2 | Source3 | Source4 | Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature3 | Feature4 | Feature5 |
| 0 | 2819 | 1942 | 103 | 161 | 477 | 136 | 179 | 278 | 330 | 140 | 743 |
| 1 | 3353 | 2342 | 104 | 195 | 576 | 135 | 209 | 285 | 416 | 147 | 947 |
| 2 | 1719 | 1273 | 49 | 74 | 272 | 51 | 105 | 158 | 201 | 101 | 437 |

What is the right test to examine the differences between the groups in the 2 different variables(source and feature)?

Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you want to examine two different potential associations:  Group and Source, and Group and Feature.  If so, this sounds like a classic application for a chi-square test of association (or chi-square test of independence).  Or similar tests (G-test, Monte Carlo simulation).  With an effect size statistic such as Cramér's V.  Have you investigated these ?  Or are you looking to do some other analysis ?

Comment: Hi Sal, you are correct on your description. I was looking at chi-square, and at Cramer's V. But as far as I understood it that would not give me the full solution I want. I want something like an ANOVA that would give me the "source of the difference", so not just a general value. But whether group 2 is more like then group 2 to choose source 1, but less likely to choose source 2. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It's the kind of problem that takes some thinking about exactly it is that you want to know. ... I can think of a couple of different approaches in that case.  1) Use an omnibus chi-square test.  1a) Then look at a post-hoc analysis.  This might be doing pairwise chi-square tests for each pair of Group.  Even then, you might want to look at standardized residuals within each e.g. 2 x 5  table for more information about which Source is driving the difference in distribution.  1b) Or maybe just look at standardized residuals from the omnibus table for insight. <cont'>

Comment: 2) Use multinomial (logistic) regression.  Depending on the software, this may not be too difficult, and there may be options to tell you what you want to know.